# Syntax-highlighting for PXSL?

Tags: xml, development-environment, syntax-highlighting, notepad++

To mitigate some of the headache of working with XML I've been experimenting with [PXSL](http://community.moertel.com/pxsl/), an abbreviated syntax for any XML document with advanced macro capabilities. However, since it's so new, I haven't been able to find any text editors that know how to parse it for syntax highlighting.

Do you know of any editors or plug-ins that would enable this? Where would I start if I wanted to define syntax highlighting, say for Notepad++?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might check out the [PApp syntax highlighting](http://www.vim.org/htmldoc/syntax.html#papp.vim) included in VIM.

The PApp syntax file handles .papp files and, to a lesser extend, .pxml
and .pxsl files which are all a mixture of perl/xml/html/other using xml
as the top-level file format. By default everything inside phtml or pxml
sections is treated as a string with embedded preprocessor commands. If
you set the variable:

```
:let papp_include_html=1
```

in your startup file it will try to syntax-hilight html code inside phtml
sections, but this is relatively slow and much too colourful to be able to
edit sensibly ;) (aka, pxsl is hard to parse)

The newest version of the papp.vim syntax file can usually be found at [http://papp.plan9.de](http://papp.plan9.de/).

Answer (score 1):

I am not a Notepad++ user, but I can recommend you to use UltraEdit and its custom syntax highlighting feature.

It already supports several languages as stated below:

http://www.ultraedit.com/downloads/extras.html

And the best side is, you can build your own word file by taking a look at the examples.

The worst part on the other hand, UltraEdit is not free..

Answer (score 1):

I'd recomend PSpad, suports a lot of languages syntax coloring and it's freeware.
www.pspad.com

Answer (score 1):

To enable syntax highlighting for PXSL .pxl (or any other atypical file extension) in Notepad++, you need to:

1. install the XML Tools plugin
2. tell Notepad++ that .pxl (and whatever other) file extensions should be highlighted as XML.

For (1), click "Plugins" -> "Plugin Manager" -> "Show Plugin Manager".  Scroll down and check off XML Tools, then install.

Once you've restarted Notepad++, do (2):

- click "Settings" -> "Styler Configurator..."
- In the "Language" list, select "XML"
- In the "User ext" text box, type in "pxl"

---

*e.g.*, when I wanted my [DITA](http://dita.xml.org/) source files to be highlighted as XML, I added "dita ditamap" in the User ext text box to highlight files with .dita or .ditamap extensions.